# Switching to iFrame in cypress equivalent to Protractor

Tags: javascript, iframe, cypress

I have a challenge in my SUT (a web page) that has a log in a iFrame embedded as javascript.
The same challenge was solved when I used Protractor like this:

```
var driver = browser.driver;
var loc = by.tagName('iframe');
var el = driver.findElement(loc);

browser.switchTo().frame(el);
```

Is it possible to do this kind of switch in cypress scripting?

Could someone give an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

[This is not currently possible.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/known-issues.html#Iframes) However, there is a workaround for performing actions and assertions within iframes. Here's [a really nice example](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136#issuecomment-390026390) from [tscott-au](https://github.com/tscott-au) on GitHub:

```
cy.get('#myIframe')
  .then(function ($iframe) {
    const $jbody = $iframe.contents().find('body')
    const $body = $jbody[0]
    cy.wrap($body).find('#myField').should('exist')
  })
})
```

---

There are some caveats to this workaround. See [this link](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136#issuecomment-248619707) for more info, but here's a quote:

> ...you can ... target these elements and potentially perform actions on them [but] you cannot return them or use them in cypress commands.

Comment: But in my concrete example this works in Protractor: 
var driver = browser.driver;
var loc = by.tagName('iframe');
var el = driver.findElement(loc);
as in the name of the frame is iframe, but writing const $jbody = $iframe.contents().find('iframe') does not work

Comment: In the example, the `.find()` on the `$iframe` contents is targeting an element within the iframe, not the iframe itself as in `$iframe.contents().find('iframe')`.

Comment: So if the name of the ifame is "bankid2_iframe" and the field I want to check if exists is called "username", how would you write the function?

Comment: What do you mean by name? Are you talking about the ID? Your `cy.get("...")` should contain a CSS selector that targets the iframe, and your `.wrap($body).find("...")` should contain a CSS selector that targets the element you're wanting to check the existence of.